# Hadoop mapreduce application failed due to OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, druid

I'm using Apache Druid to ingest data(type: index_hadoop), but the index task failed, there's no useful infomation in index log. Then I find the MR application(application name: OELandingType-determine_partitions_hashed-Optional.of([2022-12-25T00:00:00.000Z/20222-12-26T00:00:00.000Z], OELandingType is my druid datasource name)) was failed, the error in yarn log says:

```
2023-01-05 17:04:55,291 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Adding job token for job_1672909107121_0001 to jobTokenSecretManager
2023-01-05 17:04:55,349 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Not uberizing job_1672909107121_0001 because: too many reduces;
2023-01-05 17:04:55,397 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Input size for job job_1672909107121_0001 = 115735. Number of splits = 1
2023-01-05 17:08:51,299 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.<init>(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.<init>(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl.<init>(TaskImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.ReduceTaskImpl.<init>(ReduceTaskImpl.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.createReduceTasks(JobImpl.java:1569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:1008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$JobEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceStart(MRAppMaster.java:1207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1654)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1583)
2023-01-05 17:09:05,108 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2023-01-05 17:09:45,419 ERROR [Thread-0] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread Thread[Thread-0,5,main] threw an Throwable, but we are shutting down, so ignoring this
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

You can see from the log the data size is quite small, `Input size for job job_1672909107121_0001 = 115735. Number of splits = 1`, following are some other information    which may be relevant:

1. Hadoop 2.8.5 based on yarn, total 4 x m5a.xlarge(4 Core 16G memory, 100G SSD GP3) , 3 were used as yarn node (12G Mem and 4 vCore)
2. yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb = 6144
3. yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts = -Xmx4915m
4. mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 3072
5. mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 6144

Comment: If the data is small, why do you need 4-6GB of memory per mapreduce task to process it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer in production the data size may be larger, like 5GB data to ingest per task. Here I try to use a small file to make sure the problem is not caused by data size.

Comment: Sure, but files are broken into chunks up to 128 MB by mapreduce, by default, assuming that the file is splitable, so the size of the entire file isn't relevant. That being said, what happens when you halve each of those memory settings?